# Find the value of the segment AP in the inscribed quadrilateral of the question below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

A circle is inscribed in a quadrilateral $ABCD$ ($M$ and $N$ are points of tangency with $AD$ and $BC$),$AC$ intersects $MN$ at $P$, such that $CP=10$, $CN=8$ and $AM=4$.Calculate $AP$. (S:$AP=5$)

I made the drawing but I can only determine the values $CE=8$, $AF=4$.
$4+BF+DE+8=4+DM+8+BN⟹BF+DE=BN+DM$

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quadrilateral $ABCD$ with chord of inscribed circle meeting $AC$ at $P$. Find ratio $AP$ : $PC$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963479/quadrilateral-abcd-with-chord-of-inscribed-circle-meeting-ac-at-p-find-ra) - found using a [site search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeometry%5D+circle+inscribed+quadrilateral). This other question has somewhat different numbers, and asks for a ratio, but the result is basically the same, i.e., we get $\frac{PA}{PC}=\frac{AM}{CN}=\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$, so $PA=\frac{1}{2}(PC)=5$.

Comment: So they told you that $MN$ is a diameter?

Comment: FYI, in your result of $BF+DE=BN+DN$ (note $DN$ should be $DM$), we can actually more specifically get that $\lvert BF\rvert = \lvert BN\rvert$ and $\lvert DE\rvert = \lvert DM\rvert$. Also, the comments on the other question have some useful info, including a link to [Go Geometry (Problem Solutions)](https://gogeometry.blogspot.com/2008/08/elearn-geometry-problem-152.html) which has a solution there as well.

Comment: @JohnOmielan   excellent...it was very useful. Thank you